# JSF Concurrency - Launch threads from managed beans to call Service

Tags: multithreading, jsf, concurrency

I have a ManagedBean that can call a Service that accesses the database. That service has the @Service and @Transactional annotations, and since it is a service that has functions to mess around in the database, it obviously is called in a number of places.

In my frontend, in my managed bean I want to call for a function that is like a job, a batch, and it can take quite a while. The job can take like 1 minute and I don't want the client to be waiting on the frontend that long, since there may be jobs that can take like an hour.

I'll post an example of the code I have currently (just consider I have in my xhtml file some button that calls the launchBatch() function):

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class JobLauncherController {

        @ManagedProperty("#{serviceController}")
        private ServiceController serviceController;

        public void launchBatch(String code) {
            switch (code) {
            case Constants.Batch.BATCH_1:
                Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serviceController.getBatchService().batch1();
                    }
                });
                t1.start();
                break;
            case Constants.Batch.BATCH_2:
                Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Date date = new Date();
                        String parameters = String
                                .valueOf(date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + 
":" + date.getSeconds());
                        serviceController.getBatchService().batch2(parameters);
                    }
                });
                t2.start();
                break;
            case Constants.Batch.BATCH_3:
                Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serviceController.getBatchService().batch3();
                    }
                });
                t3.start();
                break;
            case Constants.Batch.BATCH_4:
                Thread t4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serviceController.getBatchService().batch4();
                    }
                });
                t4.start();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            showGrowl();
        }

        public void showGrowl() {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "",
 "Job launched sucessfully!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growlPanel", message);
        }

        public ServiceController getServiceController() {
            return serviceController;
        }

        public void setServiceController(ServiceController serviceController) {
            this.serviceController = serviceController;
        }


    }
```

My service (interface):

```
public interface AppBatchService {

    public void batch1();

    public void batch2(Object parameters);

    public void batch3();

    public void batch4();

}
```

And the implementation

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AppBatchServiceImpl implements AppBatchService {
//code to implementation goes here
}
```

So this is launching a thread successfully, because when I debug this, I have put the functions batchN to sleep for like a minute, and the code keeps flowing to my showGrowl() and my showGrowl(), ends the code flow successfully, the problem is at frontend, because it doesn't complete the action of the button while the thread I launched is running.

Is there a specific way to start threads when dealing with JSF/Primefaces to end the action, without changing the service I have? I've seen solutions with @Stateless and with @Asynchronous on the functions, but I cannot change this structure.

Comment: `@Service` is not a Java-se not a JSF annotation. And if you don't want to change the services, create wrappers. The answers you found are the answers you need. Plain  and simple

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, thank you for you answer. I have changed it all to use the Stateless and Asynchronous to test it and the problem stays the same. The problem is at the front end. I have a commandButton that has  in action="#{jobLauncherController.launchBatch(foo)}" and from what I've read, this fires an Ajax request to the Controller. At the controller it is all run like it should, it calls the other functions asynchronously and ends the function, but for some reason, the Ajax success is not sent until that same thread is finished. Any ideias how to complete the Ajax request with java?

Comment: If the Ajax call does not return immediately there is something wrong in what you do to make the server side run async.

Comment: I don't know enough about EJBs to know if this will help, but you could try making the Runnable classes their own top level classes instead of defining them locally, and see if that helps.